# SharePoint Online Json formatting with date based check

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to get something to work on SharePoint Online with JSON column formatting.
What i have currently been able to achieve was, if a column is filled in ==> fill green if empty fill orange.
I would like to convert this to a date-based check.

For example:
When the column contains data = Fill it as green & show text in white

If todays date = or is less then the date in LaunchDate Column AND the field is empty ==> Fill it red

todays date equals or is more then 1 month before LaunchDate ==> Fill Yellow

1 month or less before launch date =:=> fill Orange.

I am struggeling with stringing this all together.
Any ideas?

[image]

After applying solution suggested below i get as result(i emptied an expired field to illustrate:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the rules as I understand them:

- Column has a value: **Green with White text**
- Column has no value and `LaunchDate` is in the past: **Red**
- Column has no value and `LaunchDate` is within 30 days: **Orange**
- Column has no value and `LaunchDate` is more than 30 days out: **Yellow**

Assuming those are correct, this format should work. Just apply it to each column (column settings > format this column > advanced mode) you'd like it applied to and be sure `LaunchDate` remains part of the view.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(length(@currentField), 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-white', if([$LaunchDate] <= @now, 'ms-bgColor-red', if([$LaunchDate] <= addDays(@now,30), 'ms-bgColor-orange', 'ms-bgColor-yellow')))"
  }
}
```

[image]

I used the [ms-bgColor-*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/ms-bgColor/) classes since that was easier to map to your preferred colors. However, the [sp-css-backgroundColor-*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/sp-css-backgroundColor/) or [sp-field-severity--*](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/groupings/classes/sp-field/) classes may be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your swift reply, but I seem to be either missing something or something seems to go wrong :) i applied the formatting as you specified and everything is showing red. Do note we use european date formate so dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I made a tweak to the format to make it easier to read and add the schema. I also hadn't tested it, but now I have and added a screenshot. Are you sure `LaunchDate` is the internal name of your column?

Comment: Hi Chris, You are a SAINT8